# Delete duplicates element sublist

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm wondering if this is possible to delete duplicate elements if **a=b** and **b=a** using deleteduplicates or any simple way.

```
l1 = {{284, 220}, {220, 284}, {1210, 1184}, {1184, 1210}, {2924, 
  2620}, {2620, 2924}, {5564, 5020}, {5020, 5564}, {6368, 
  6232}, {6232, 6368}, {10856, 10744}, {10744, 10856}, {14595, 12285}}

DeleteDuplicatesBy[
l1], First == Last && Last==First]
```

For exemple, I would like to delete *{284,220}, {1210,1184}, ...*

Thank you

Comment: `l1 // DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ l1]
(*{{220, 284}, {1184, 1210}, {2620, 2924}, {5020, 5564}, {6232, 6368}, {10744, 10856}, {12285, 14595}}*)
```

Comment: It's a (+1) from me. Just as a comment one could use `Union`, i.e `DeleteDuplicates[Union /@ l1]`

Comment: Hi, friend! I'm glad to see you here. I hope everything went well with your move. You're right, it works great with `Union`.

Comment: Hello.. Still trying to figure out some stuff, but it's getting better on a daily basis, thanks! Hope you're also well :-)

Comment: I'm coming out of a flu, but everything is going well so far, thanks! :-)

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, since @E. Chan-López gave the proper answer let's see with what else we can come up.

Suggested solution

`Gather[Sort /@ l1][[All, 1]]`

Comparison with the `DeleteDuplicates` solution

`DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ l1] - Gather[Sort /@ l1][[All, 1]]`

> `{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}`

Answer (score 5):

```
l1 = {{284, 220}, {220, 284}, {1210, 1184}, {1184, 1210}, {2924, 
   2620}, {2620, 2924}, {5564, 5020}, {5020, 5564}, {6368, 
   6232}, {6232, 6368}, {10856, 10744}, {10744, 10856}, {14595, 
   12285}};

ConnectedComponents[Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ l1]]
```

> ```
> {{5020, 5564}, {6368, 6232}, {14595, 12285}, {2620, 2924}, {220, 
>   284}, {10856, 10744}, {1184, 1210}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {{12, 10}, {10, 12}, {20, 20}, {20, 20}, {16, 15}, {12, 10}};
```

I would suggest

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[SymmetricDifference] @ list
```

{{12, 10}, {20, 20}, {16, 15}}

because it doesn't sort the sublists. "Why should the unpaired `{16, 15}` become `{15, 16}`"? one could ask pedantically.

Compare with the accepted answer:

```
DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ list]
```

{{10, 12}, {20, 20}, {15, 16}}

`SymmetricDifference` came with V 13.1.

Comment: (+1) An important point IMO.